# Merge two list in Linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq, class

I have two Lists

```
List<Product> Products; 
List<Showcase> Showcases;
```

Product class contains ShowcaseID which is ID value of Showcase Class

and Showcase class like ;

```
public class Showcase
{
 public int ID { get; set;}
 //.....

 public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

**Expected Output ;**

```
List<Showcase> MergedList; // Same of Showcase class from beginning but contains All Product groupped by ShowcaseID
```

ofc I can merge this objects with loops but I want to do it with Linq , What is the simplest way ?

Comment: what is the output you expect ?

Comment: You need to join the two lists using a common field.  See webpage : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Comment: I wrote expected output , I dont want any other class , just copy the Products to Showcases List wich related with Showcase ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the ForEach method for List

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z(v=vs.110).aspx

```
List<Product> Products; 
List<Showcase> Showcases;

Showcases.ForEach(s => s.Products.AddRange(Products.Where(p => p.ShowcaseID == s.ID)));
```

**UPDATE 1**

You can use the following if you don't want to lose Showcases list.

```
List<Showcase> MergedList = new List<Showcase>();
MergedList.AddRange(Showcases.Select(s => new Showcase { Products = products.Where(p => p.ShowcaseID == s.ID).ToList() }));
```